# Extension of $x^2$ to the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, self-learning

Take $f(x)=x^2, x \in \mathbf{R}$. We know that the analytic extension of $f$ to the complex plane is $g(z)=z^2, z \in \mathbf{C}$ , or also $f(x+iy)=(x^2-y^2)+2ixy$. This can be checked via the following steps:

1. Observing that $g$ restricted to the real axes is equal to $f$
2. Via the Cauchy-Riemann conditions we can prove analyticity (complex differentiability)

But the steps $1,2$ seem a bit too much to prove something that seems or should be "obvious". Here is my question:

QUESTION: is there an "obvious"/"trivial by construction" reason why $g(z)=z^2$ is the analytic extension of $f(x)=x^2$ ?

I just put the question as an example in term of a quadratic polynomial but this should apply also to higher order ones.

Comment: Enough to handle every monomial (also polynomial by linearity): (i) Prove $z$ is analytic. (ii) Prove if $f,\,g$ are analytic so is $fg$. Both steps are trivial by Cauchy-Riemann, especially if you write it as Eq. (2) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Conformal_mappings).

Comment: It depends on what tools you have at your disposal. $g(z) = z^2$ is analytic as the product of the (analytic) identity function with itself.

Comment: 1. It is obviously an extension.
2. It is analytic because it is a polynomial.

Comment: It is enough to use differentiation rules such as $(f+g)' = f'+g', (fg)' = f'g+fg'$, which also holds for complex differentiable functions. The proof is actually almost same as what you did in calculus/real analysis. Then you can verify that all polynomials are analytic(with derivative same as in real variable).

Comment: Thanks. So according to these comments I should consider this as a non-trivial result to prove (i.e. not evident from the definitions?). To answer @MartinR, I would like an argument using just the definition of complex numbers and of complex differentiability. But not other properties like that the product of diff functions is differentiable (unless these are made trivial by definition).

Comment: @Thomas: It is not clear to me what you are looking for.  A polynomial in $z$ is an analytic function. That is “obvious” if you know that sums and products of analytic functions are again analytic. If you don't want to use that fact then you have to verify analycity with the CR equations.

Comment: Maybe the connection I am looking for is that the product of analytic extensions is the analytic extension of the product... i understand that the question is not well defined I may remove it.

Comment: @MartinR just a final question. The analyitic extension of a monomial x^n has the same form, z^n, where the product between complex number has a well defined definition. Doesn't this suggest that the product in complex space has been defined exactly so that this holds? And, after your comments, the product in complex space has been exactly defined so that the product of analytic functions is analytic?

Comment: Hope the previous comment does not generate further confusion, it is not easy for me to write these type of questions regarding intuition/learning/understanding in a clear way...

Comment: A function is "analytic" if it is expressible as a power series on some non-empty open set about every point of its domain. This is the generic definition of analycity applicable to $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb C^n$ for all $n$. Polynomials are themselves power series whose coefficients are eventually $0$, and therefore converge to the function everywhere. Thus all polynomials are automatically analytic.

Comment: Still I think that we are using under the carpet the definition of multiplication in complex space and the reasons that makes all things come together...

Comment: A function on an open subset of $\Bbb R$ only has an analytic continuation to $\Bbb C$ if it is analytic itself. Recall that while in $\Bbb C$, analytic is equivalent to "differentiable on an open set", in $\Bbb R$, even being infinitely differentiable is not sufficient. Analycity is a very complex condition that in - and only in - $\Bbb C$ reduces to a much simpler one. Your seemingly obvious fact actually has very deep dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. So your point of view is that the fact that z^n is the analytic extension of x^n is a nontrivial fact that one could not have guessed if using just the definition of complex differentiation?

Comment: If you want to "unfold" these dependencies in an answer I would upvote it 

Comment: Yes it is a non-trivial fact because the very concept of "analytic continuation" is non-trivial by its nature. That it corresponds to just replacing a real variable with a complex variable in polynomials is a trivial consequence of polynomials being power series that converge everywhere. That it corresponds to replacing a real variable with a complex variable in many transcendental functions is a result of those functions being defined either by power series, or by differential equations that are effectively equivalent to power series.

Comment: And that "differentiable on an open set" is equivalent to being analytic on $\Bbb C$ is a consequence of one of the most celebrated results in all of mathematics, and is most definitely not trivial.

Comment: So what you want to say is that since the connection holomorphic <-> analytic is non trivial and the fact that the analytic extension of x^n is z^n js trivial by the analiticity condition, there cannot be a trivial way to see this starting instead from the homolorphic condition ?